# Gitlab masking variables

Tags: gitlab-ci

I can't seem to mask a variable on Gitlab CI -

I'm trying to upload a ssh private key and no matter what I do it refuses to mask it.

That is I'm trying to store a private key *on Gitlab* for use by the Gitlab runner that my production servers have public keys for. I'm not asking about how to introduce it to the runner during the build as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822678/gitlab-ci-use-ed25519-private-key)

I'm using a ed25519 key so the characters aren't all base 64 to start with.

So after generating the key

```
$ cat gitlab
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmU....etc etc
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I piped it to base64

```
$ cat gitlab|base64
```

No joy.

Gitlab also seemed to be introducing newlines into the pasted text/variable field

So I did

```
$ cat gitlab|base64|tr -d '\r'
```

and even

```
$ cat gitlab|base64|tr -d '\r'|xclip
```

I found [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019015/how-to-mask-aws-secret-access-key-in-gitlab-ci)
so what the hell

```
$ cat gitlab|base64|base32|tr -d '\r'|xclip
```

all with no joy.

Anyone got this working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me `cat gitlab | base64 -w0` works.

In you absolutely want to use `tr`, you'd use `tr -d '\n'` instead.

**EDIT**: of course you also need to unbase64 it when using it.

Here's an example which should clear the confusion:

```
$ echo secret > gitlab
$ MY_SECRET_ENCODED="$(cat gitlab | base64 -w0)"

$ echo $MY_SECRET_ENCODED
c2VjcmV0Cg==

$ MY_SECRET_DECODED = "$(echo MY_SECRET_ENCODED | base64 -d)"
$ echo $MY_SECRET_DECODED
secret
```

Here MY_SECRET_ENCODED is your variable in the interface, MY_SECRET_DECODED is what you use in your script.

Comment: That worked to get it masked (thanks)... but the Gitlab deploy fails. Unmasked, it deploys ok, masked it doesn't. Sigh. Why does Gitlab make stuff so hard?

Comment: @PierreBrasseau: added an edit to clear the confusion, ask if unclear.

Comment: <facepalm> forgot the decode. For any other unfortunate here's the change in the .gitlab-ci.yml: - echo "${GITLABRUNNER_PRIVKEY}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null becomes - echo "${GITLABRUNNER_PRIVKEY}"|base64 -d| ssh-add - > /dev/null

Comment: I don't get why gitlab enforces the use of base64 encoded variables to be able to mask them if we need to decode them afterwards. base64 is not an encryption... Thanks @PierreBrasseau anyway. Did the trick for me.

Comment: Sorry but the output of `echo $MY_SECRET_DECODED` will still appear as plain text in the gitlab runner logs right?

Comment: @IMB: Yes. You need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://fullstackchronicles.io/masking-private-keys-in-ci-cd-pipelines-in-gitlab) - not pretty but effective, masks the multi-string variables.

[Result echo job screen of masked SSH-key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfAyB.png)